# Date string format convert

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

Date string1: 2022-10-30T04:45:00+00:00
Date string2: Oct 30, 2022 at 04:45 GMT

Date string1 and Date string2, i want formate is "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search before asking.

Comment: Only when you search, avoid any suggestions to use the old classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They were supplanted nearly 10 years ago by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You will need classes `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` and possibly more.

Comment: Your source strings include offset from UTC or GMT (zero in both your examples). Assuming that the offset may also be non-zero,in which time zone or at which offset do you want the result format? It will be a bad idea to retain the offset from the original string without telling the reader of the new string which it was.